# Creating Blazor Web assembly In Visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I am new to blazor web assembly. I am following a tutorial on how to create a blazor web assembly app. After creating my solution in my projects are not loaded into visual studio.

I  created a blank solution and tried to add it as an existing project. Below is the error message I got while trying to do that.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean VS 2022?

Comment: Install the needed SDK? - https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks

Comment: Am using Visual studio 2019

Comment: Thanks very @all i had to instal vs 2022 to solve the problem